# if $T_Z$ is finer than $T_Y$ then $Y\subseteq Z$?

Tags: general-topology

Well, a initial question was (already done): Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space and $Y\subseteq X$, $Z\subseteq X$. If $Y\subseteq Z$, prove $T_Z$ is finer than $T_Y$. Where, for a subset $A$ of $X$:

$T_A =${$B \cup E: B \in T, E\subseteq A$}

But I was wondering if this statement could be an iff. I mean, if $T_Z$ is finer than $T_Y$ implies $Y\subseteq Z$. I was trying, assuming $U\in T_Y$, so this open set can be written as $U = A\cup E$
for some $A\in T$ and some $E\subseteq Y$, and $U$ is also in $T_Z$, therefore the union. But I realized that the union could be not the same in the topology $T_Z$.

I don't know how to proceed and I haven't found a counterexample either.
I really appreciate any help to guide me in the right way. Thanks.

Comment: [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933), i.e. work a little harder before asking. Think of the discrete topology on $X.$

Answer (score 1):

@Anne Bauval is right: the discrete topology quickly leads to a counterexample. If $T$ is discrete (that is, $U \in T$ for any $U \subseteq X$), then $T_A = T$ for any $A$, which means that comparing $T_A$ with $T_{A'}$ will not tell you anything about how $A$ compares with $A'$.

For the smallest counterexample: if $X = \{x\}$, then $T_{\{x\}} \subseteq T_\emptyset$ but it's not true that $\{x\} \subseteq \emptyset$.

Comment: Intuitively, $T_A$ "blows up" the subset $A$. But that has no effect if $A$ was already blown up in $T$. I wonder if assuming $T_Z$ _strictly_ finer than $T_Y$ might get you somewhere, though.